# Backbone: Saving part of the collection to an array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I do have a collection and i need to go through the collection, and alter the data if necessary and push to an array.

```
 {
"Beatles": [
      {"name":"Album 1", "rate":"70"},
      {"name":"Album 2", "rate":"75"},
      {"name":"Album 3", "rate":"82"},
      {"name":"Album 4", "rate":"60"}
], 
"Purple" :[
      {"name":"Album 1", "rate":"30"},
      {"name":"Album 2", "rate":"90"},
      {"name":"Album 3", "rate":"23"},
      {"name":"Album 4", "rate":"14"}
]
}
```

// I want to go through the collection and save only the rates of Beatles album to an array, so it will look like this
    myBeattlesarray = [70,75,82,60];

what is the best way to achieve this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Underscore [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to get one field from the collection:

```
_.pluck(collection.Beatles, "rate");
```

---

```
var model = new Backbone.Model(
{
"Beatles": [
  {"name":"Album 1", "rate":"70"},
  {"name":"Album 2", "rate":"75"},
  {"name":"Album 3", "rate":"82"},
  {"name":"Album 4", "rate":"60"}
], 
"Purple" :[
  {"name":"Album 1", "rate":"30"},
  {"name":"Album 2", "rate":"90"},
  {"name":"Album 3", "rate":"23"},
  {"name":"Album 4", "rate":"14"}
]
}
);

var beatles = model.get("Beatles");
var rates = _.pluck(beatles, "rate");

console.log(rates);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k5AVE/

Comment: Thank you for the help. I need to achieve this result; [70,75,82,60], as i am expected to send the array list.. Will pluck let me do this?. Because i was thinking the only way to be able to do this was similar to this, but still not getting what i need.. 

var rates= [];
for ( var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
   rates.push(collection.at(i));
}

Comment: @Skyrim1 yes, I think pluck should work, based on what you've described.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/k5AVE/

Comment: Thank you, this is great and what i needed.... One question though, what if i need to alter the values, lets say if the rate is blank, i want to set the value to 0 before saving to the array.. then i guess this pluck wouldn't work.. if that's the case, how can i approach to that issue?

Comment: @Skyrim1 you could use `each` for that I guess (Backbone or Javascript works).  See: http://jsfiddle.net/k5AVE/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have backbone.js/underscore.js or you don't need to, here is a light array/collection libraries that does *pluck()* and all other operations, [jsList](https://github.com/tadessetdk/jsList). You may check the unit tests for sample code.

For your problem, could writer

```
var result = beattles.pluck('rate');
```

If you need to extract more than one field, you could use

```
var result = beattles.pluck(['rate', 'name']);
```